# CSS Drop Down Menu - How to target Child Element?

Tags: css, wordpress, menu

Page in Question:
http://dev.cd-duplication-in-the-uk.com/disc-printing/screen/

http://jsfiddle.net/7maSx/2/ -- I would like the menu with the blue sub menu to always show

I have a 100% CSS Menu similar to this example which has been developed into a WordPress 3.0 menu for a theme I've been developing...

```
<nav class="main">
 <ul>

   <li>Main 1
     <ul>
       <li>Sub 1</li>
       <li>Sub 2</li>
       <li>Sub 3</li>
     </ul>
   </li>

   <li>Main 2
     <ul>
       <li>Sub 1</li>
       <li>Sub 2</li>
     </ul>
    </li>

   <li>Main 3</li>

 </ul>
</nav>
```

With the following (relevant) CSS for form/function

```
nav.main ul li { display: inline; float: left; list-style: none; }
nav.main ul:first-child { position: relative; }/* for the position of sub menus */
nav.main li ul { display: none; position:absolute; top: 30px; left: 0px; z-index: 10; }
nav.main li:hover ul  { display: block; }
```

...and this CSS to color the Main (parent) and the Sub(child) page which the user is on.

```
ul.menu li.current-menu-parent a {color: #036;}
ul.sub-menu li.menu-item a {color: #999;}
ul.sub-menu li.current_page_item a {color: #036;}
```

I'm looking for a way to keep the Sub Menu open if one of the li elements is the .current_page_item

Right now both the Parent and Child li menu elements have the correct styling, but I can't figure out how to keep the sub-menu open.

What would you all suggest?

Kind Regards,
Clint

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this so it shows the sub-menu on hover too:

```
nav.main li:hover ul, nav.main li:hover ul li  { display: block; }
```

But there is a gap between the main and sub menus you'll have to close-up as well. If the cursor falls in the gap the menu will close.

```
nav.main li ul { display: none; position:absolute; padding-top: 30px; left: 0px; z-index: 10; }
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/aBtbN/

Comment: Thanks for having a look, but I think what I need is to have the sub menu stay visible if that's what page you're on. http://jsfiddle.net/aBtbN/3/ - like if the li has a class of .active, i want that sub-menu to stay open.

Comment: You need to use JavaScript to so this, or have the server code change the class name on the current element so that you can make a CSS statement (like .active{}) to keep that segment open. You can't do this with CSS alone.